# Metabase displays wrong time format

Tags: metabase

My Data are stored in a `MySql` Database and i use `Metabase`to display the data.

In `phpMyAdmin`everything looks like it should, but in `Metabase` the Dates are displayed like they should. The two `datetimes` types do not really matter but the `time` type looks like a `date` altough it's a `time`.

What can i do so that the `time` is displayed correctly?

**Table Structure:**

[image]

**Table Data:**

[image]

**Metabase:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to force date format using DATE_FORMAT/TIME_FORMAT in the output fields list:

```
DATE_FORMAT(started, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as started,
TIME_FORMAT(testDuration, '%H:%i:%s') as testDuration
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding something, there is a wheel setting button that you can change the format for timing...[image: setting button]

and then -->:[image: change time format]